# C: Can there be two main() functions in a program?

Tags: c, standards

I saw other questions about having two main()'s in C program:

> **I'm using CodeBlocks**

But please consider this program:

```
void main()
{
    void main()
    {
        printf("hello!");
    }
    printf("World!");

}
```

prints only "World!".

- I'm actually writing these kind of code pieces to check what's happening under the hood.
- I somehow get the doubts( as i get errors and unexpected behaviours in my programs ) by writing weird codes but I'm unable to know why they happened
- Is there any reference to C language that i can refer to?
  Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `main` must return `int`. Anyway, in C++, a local `main` is legal, but I'm not sure about C. The one reference to truly be relied on is [the standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Comment: @chris are you saying that because i kept return 0?.

Comment: @sandeep no, that is what the standard mandates.

Comment: You did not call the second `main` function.  Why should it print anything but `World!`?

Comment: Standard C doesn't even support nested functions...

Comment: thanks for the [Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)  @chris.

Comment: Haha, but still there exist only one main.....because you have changed the meaning of the second main to fun1......by using #define preprocessor directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard C and C++ do not support nested functions, but:

1. GCC supports nested functions in C, as a language extension.
2. The D language, which is C-related, has nested functions.

and CodeBlocks use GCC compiler only, hence you're are not getting any error.

For the question

> about having two `main()` in C program

No you can't, this is how compiler interprets where to start executing the program. It will take one of the main as local.

Also,

> you are not getting "hello" printed

because when compiler starts executing your first `main()` function, it takes the second `main()` as local, and because you haven't called the second `main()`, the string doesn't get printed.

Answer (score 9):

> C: Can there be two main() functions in a program?

No.

And the code you posted is not valid C anyway, there are no nesting functions in C.

Comment: That answer truly gets the point. And I wonder why the original code is posted before compiling on oneself's own computer!

Comment: @lulyon Maybe he's using `-std=gnu99` all over the place. GCC'n'friends have a handful of weird extensions which some people love to rely upon.

Answer (score 0):

No, there can't be two `main` functions in `C`, or in any other programming language. The code you posted is not a valid `C` program. It will NOT compile.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Having two main functions in C is possible. It could be done by messing up the compiler using  macros/pre-defined functions. Here is the code snippet,

```
#include    <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    printf("Inside 1st main\n");
        func1();
}
#define main func1
void main()
{
    printf("Inside 2nd main\n");
}
```

- Keep the preprocessor be as it is. Else you would get error.